# Android Studio: scrollTo in Horizontal function isn't working

Tags: java, android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview, scrollto

I'm making this converter app and have spent some time trying to figure out how to work this scrollTo() function to scroll to the button I desire it to be focused in a Horizontal Scroll View.

I've implemented the following to my onCreate:

```
        final HorizontalScrollView HscrollView1 = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hsView1);
        final HorizontalScrollView HscrollView2 = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.hsView2);

        final Button cmBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cm_id);
        final Button KmBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.km_id);
        final Button mmBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mm_id);

        HscrollView1.scrollTo((int) mmBtn.getX(), 0);
        HscrollView2.scrollTo((int) cmBtn.getX(), 0);
```

After running APK, it won't scroll to mm and cm button when the app starts (unlike what I wrote in the code)

It seems so frustrating to me with this scrollview and it would be awesome if someone can help me here at 5am (est)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
    HscrollView1.scrollTo((int) mmBtn.getX(), 0);
    HscrollView2.scrollTo((int) cmBtn.getX(), 0);
```

with

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    HscrollView1.scrollTo((int) mmBtn.getX(), 0);
                    HscrollView2.scrollTo((int) cmBtn.getX(), 0);
                }
            }, 500);
```

and run your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am not quite sure on what you mean by "executing"

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: wow thank you! It did work well on my device as well! One last thing! If I want to center the view (not all the way to the left), how would math work there?? Thank you once again!

Comment: and I am not able to get your next query